# How do i get the uid from a newly created user using firebase , then use the uid to populate a database with the remaining data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am usinf firebase authentication and firebase database to create a user account for my app. I have authentication working, it creates the account, but when it moves on to save user details to the database, its saying that the key is empty, even though i was able to console log the key and the value shows.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import { emailRegex } from "../components/Utilities/validations";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "../components/firebase";
import { ref, set } from "firebase/database";
import { database } from "../components/firebase";

export default function () {
  const [userID, setUserID] = useState("");
  const validate = (values) => {
    const errors = {};
    if (!values.repassword !== values.password) {
      errors.repassword = "passwords do not match";
    }

    if (!emailRegex.test(values.email)) {
      errors.email = "invalid email";
    }
    if (values.phone.length < 10) {
      errors.phone = "enter valid phone number including area code";
    }
  };

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      repassword: "",
      first_name: "",
      last_name: "",
      phone: "",
      street_address: "",
      street_address_2: "",
      city: "",
      state: "",
      postal_code: "",
      country: "",
    },
    validate,
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, values.email, values.password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
          const user = userCredential.user;
          console.log(auth.currentUser.uid);
          setUserID(auth.currentUser.uid);
          console.log("This is my key " + auth.currentUser.uid);
        })
        .then(() =>
          set(ref(database, "users/" + userID), {
            email: email,
            first_name: first_name,
            last_name: last_name,
            phone: phone,
            street_address: street_address,
            street_address_2: street_address_2,
            city: city,
            state: state,
            postal_code: postal_code,
            country: country,
            userID: auth.currentUser.uid,
          })
        )

        .catch((error) => {
          const errorCode = error.code;
          const errorMessage = error.message;
          console.log(errorMessage);
        });
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

React useState hook is asynchronous. So, it won't have the UID that you are setting at the time when you're using it. So it's better to use it directly from `auth.currentUser.uid` instead of setting it into a hook and then using it.

```js
...
set(ref(database, "users/" + auth.currentUser.uid), {
...
```

Comment: even when i use auth.currentUser.uid, it is still null

Comment: Could you show the error please ?

Comment: HI thanks for your effort, I used an async function instead, and it worked, ill update the code to reflect the changes I made.

Answer (score 0):

I used an async function instead, this allowed me to have access to the auth.currentUser object in the then chain

```js
const createUserAccount = async (values) => {
      const response = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        email,
        password
      )
        .then((user) => {
          if (auth.currentUser.uid !== null) {
            set(ref(database, "users/" + auth.currentUser.uid), {
              first_name: fname,
              last_name: lname,
              phone: phone,
              email: email,
              address: address,
            });

            console.log("data written to db");
          } else {
            console.log("empty uid");
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          const errorCode = error.code;
          const errorMessage = error.message;
          setErrors({ email: errorMessage });

          console.log(errorMessage);
        });
```